# Separating strings as different arguments (don't know how to word this lol)

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

So I am working on a discord bot that would look something like this:
!modify [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2] [3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 2] ...(and so on, accepting as many more strings as possible)

What this would do is have the bot output [6, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 8, 4] (So the bot took the two strings and multiplied the numbers inside of them.

The problem I have is that I'm stuck trying to figure out how to have the bot recognize to separate arguments at a ']'

Also, how would I have the bot multiply the numbers inside of the string together???

Current code:

```
@client.command()
async def modify(ctx, *, arg1=None):
  if ctx.channel.id != 850806578125864981:
    return 
  else:
    #bruh
```

My brain is fried

Comment: I think I've taken on a project way outside of my skill level lol

Comment: how is the argument passed in to the function? I am not familiar with discord but the rest of the logic seems straightforward

Comment: Keep in mind that there will always be a minimum and maximum of 13 numbers (can be decimals too) inside each pair of []s

Comment: A problem I ran into was that the bot was trying to multiply '[2.5', '[6' and '[2' or '3]' and '4]' which will obviously output an error

Comment: does each pairs of [] contains the same amout of number ?

Comment: yes, always 13 numbers

Comment: is there always 2 sets of [] or can it be more ?

Comment: There can be more, sometimes up to as many as 13. This will be useful for a game I help balance using what is known as a g.stat which is basically that string of 13 numbers

Comment: do you want the bot to send the final result ?

Comment: For now, don't worry about that. I suppose you can store the final result as a variable inside the function but I'm going to add the embed message that'll send it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go :

```
@client.command()
async def modify(ctx, *args):
    if ctx.channel.id != 850806578125864981:
        return
    else:
        sets = [] # stocking every sets found
        subset = [] #I call a 'set' a pair of brackets

        for arg in args:
            if arg == 'g.basic': # append the set you wanted
                sets.append([18.25, 1.4, .1, 1, 2, .2, 1, 4.5, 1, 1, 1, 15, 1])
                continue # go directly to the next iteration without finishing the loop

            subset.append(float(''.join([car for car in arg if car.isnumeric() or car == '.']))) # just extracting the numerical part of the element
            if ']' in arg: #closing a set
                sets.append(subset)
                subset = [] # creating a new one

        output = [*sets[0]] # number of the first set

        for s in sets[1:]: # looping over every other sets
            for i in range(len(s)):
                output[i] *= s[i] # multiplying the numbers together

        await ctx.send(f'{output}')
```

I put some comments to explain my answer but if you have any question ask me

Comment: Poggers! Thank you! There is one slight problem though, putting a decimal in one of the places causes the answer to go haywire. For example: !modify [2.5, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2] [3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 2] will output [75, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 8, 4]

Comment: yeah you were right i forgot about decimals but I edited it and it should be fixed ;) edit: not it's not wait a second I'm fiwing it

Comment: now it's fixed sorry for being stupid lol

Comment: YESSSSS thank you so much! And you're not stupid at all, lol. I'm gonna study your code now and see what you did, this info may help me when coding in the future :)

Comment: I'm solving leetcode's problem to improve and I think it starts to pay off just by looking at my code I'm thinking to myself that I would not have be able to do this like 2 months ago, this is great for improving if you want to try it it's free

Comment: I know it's a while later, but would you happen to know how I could make it so if someone put g.basic in an argument the bot would interpret it as [18.25, 1.4, .1, 1, 2, .2, 1, 4.5, 1, 1, 1, 15, 1]

Ex: !modify g.basic

Comment: yeah no problem I'm modifying my answer !

Comment: it's done I modified my answer

Comment: LETS GOOOO, you are the pog!

Comment: no problem mate I'm glad you're happy with my answers